# Unable to separate Express 4.13.1 Routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, url, express

Writing my first app with NodeJS. I have a MongoDB w/ two schemas "blurbs" and "users". I want to be able to setup APIs for both via localhost/api/blurbs and localhost/api/users. However, both URLs return the information for the "blurbs". Any help is very much appreciated. Here my code:

/models/db.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Connect to the database
var dbURI = 'mongodb:/\/localhost/scuba-noodle';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// Creating the user schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  "firstName": String,
  "lastName": String,
  "userId": String,
  "avatar": Buffer,
  "email": { type: String, unique: true },
  "created": {type: Date, default: Date.now },
  "loggedIn": Boolean,
  "lastLogin": Date,
  "noOfBlurbs": Number,
  "blurbs": [null],
  "votedOnBlurbs": [null],
  "rating": Number
});

// Exporting the user schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// Creating the blurb schema
var BlurbSchema = new Schema ({
  "author": String,
  "submitted": Date,
  "votes": Number,
  "trunk": String,
  "text": String
});

// Exporting the blurb schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('Blurb', BlurbSchema);

// Disconnect from the DB on App termination
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mongoose.connection.close(function() {
    console.log("Mongoose disconnected through app termination");
    process.exit(0);  
  });
});
```

/routes/user.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  router = express.Router(),
  User = require('../models/db');

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Incoming request...");
  next();
});

router.route('/')
  // POST
  .post(function(req, res){
    var user = new User();
    user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
    user.userName = req.body.userName;
    user.avatar = req.body.avatar || null;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.created = Date.now();
    user.loggedIn = false;
    user.lastLogin = Date.now();
    user.noOfBlurbs = 0;
    user.blurbs = [null];
    user.votedOnBlurbs = [null];
    user.rating = 0;

    user.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
          res.json({ message: "User created" });
        });  
      })
  // GET all
  .get(function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json(users);
   });
  });

router.route('/:user_id')
  //GET by ID
  .get(function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json(user);
    });
  })
  //PUT by ID
  .put(function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      user.firstName = req.body.firstName || user.firstName;  
      user.lastName = req.body.lastName || user.lastName;
      user.userName = req.body.userName || user.userName;
      user.avatar = req.body.avatar || user.avatar;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;

      user.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); }
        res.json({ message: "User update" });
      });
    });
  })
  // DELETE by ID
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    User.remove({
      _id: req.params.user_id
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json({ message: "Successfully Deleted" });
    });
  });

var userRouter = router;
module.exports = userRouter;
```

/routes/blurb.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var router = express.Router();
var Blurb = require('../models/db');

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Incoming request...");
  next();
});

router.route('/')
  // POST
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var blurb = new Blurb();
    blurb.author = req.body.author || "Anonymous";
    blurb.submitted = Date.now();
    blurb.votes = 0;
    blurb.trunk = req.body.trunk || "Unspecified";
    blurb.text = req.body.text || "Empty";

    blurb.save(function (err) {
      if(err) { res.send("Save Error: " + err); }
      res.json({ message: "Blurb Created" });
    });
  })
  // GET all
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Blurb.find(function(err, blurbs) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json(blurbs);
    });
  });

router.route('/:blurb_id')
  // GET by ID
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Blurb.findById(req.params.blurb_id, function(err, blurb) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json(blurb);
    });
  })
  // PUT by ID
  .put(function(req, res){
    Blurb.findById(req.params.blurb_id, function(err, blurb){
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      blurb.author = req.body.author || blurb.author;
      blurb.submittee = Date.now();
      blurb.votes = blurb.votes;
      blurb.trunk = req.body.trunk || blurb.trunk;
      blurb.text = req.body.text || blurb.text;

      blurb.save(function(err) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); }
        res.json({ message: 'Blurb Updated' });
      });
    });
  })
  // DELETE by ID
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    Blurb.remove({
      _id: req.params.blurb_id
    }, function(err, blurb) {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json({ message: 'Successfully Deleted' });
    });
  });

var blurbRouter = router;
module.exports = blurbRouter;
```

And finally, server.js:

```
// Call packages
var express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create the server
var app = express();

// Configure bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Setting the port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Registering the routes
app.use('/api/blurbs', require('./routes/blurb'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/user'));

// Starting the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Nodejs Server Listening on port ' + port);
```

If you have any ideas or suggestions, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: @inspired - Version 4.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you're overwriting the `module.exports` in `db.js`:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// ...

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blurb', BlurbSchema);
```

So since the latter was the last assignment, `db.js` will be exporting the `Blurb` model. You should probably instead do something like:

```
exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
exports.Blurb = mongoose.model('Blurb', BlurbSchema);
```

and change your route files appropriately:

```
var User = require('../models/db').User;
```

and

```
var Blurb = require('../models/db').Blurb;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the help, I see the problem now.